# UPDATE query with multiple INNER JOINs (syntax error)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run an update query with multiple join statements in VBA, but I keep getting "missing operator" errors. Same happens when I try to run the SQL in query builder. The SQL is:

```
UPDATE TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy
INNER JOIN TBL_LOA
ON TBL_LOA.MemberName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Member
INNER JOIN TBL_STUDY
ON TBL_STUDY.StudyName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Study
SET TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.DateLOA2 = TBL_LOA.Status
WHERE TBL_STUDY.CDB = 'B'
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE (TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy
INNER JOIN TBL_LOA
ON TBL_LOA.MemberName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Member)
INNER JOIN TBL_STUDY
ON TBL_STUDY.StudyName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Study
SET TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.DateLOA2 = TBL_LOA.Status
WHERE TBL_STUDY.CDB = 'B'
```

Comment: What if there is another JOIN ?

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE s
SET TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.DateLOA2 = TBL_LOA.STATUS
FROM TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy S
INNER JOIN TBL_LOA ON TBL_LOA.MemberName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Member
INNER JOIN TBL_STUDY ON TBL_STUDY.StudyName = TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy.Study
WHERE TBL_STUDY.CDB = 'B'
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I should have changed the other two references of 'TBL_DocReview_SingleStudy'